# preload css on my combo select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside my js file I'm applying jquery plugin to style combobox.

```
 $("#divOne").selectBoxIt().data("selectBox-selectBoxIt");
 $("#divTwo").selectBoxIt().data("selectBox-selectBoxIt");
```

On page load this plugin is applied but it's kinda slow. it first display select combo plain without any css and after 2sec. this plugin is applied.

I tried to wrap this inside dom ready on _Layout.cshtml

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#divOne").selectBoxIt().data("selectBox-selectBoxIt");
   $("#divTwo").selectBoxIt().data("selectBox-selectBoxIt");
})
```

but nothing changed.

Question is: How can I preload css on my combo select to display immediatly when content display

Comment: https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/issues/178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply CSS to the select because the select isn't what ultimately gets displayed. What the plugin creates is an entirely different set of elements. My solution would simply be to hide the original select element.

```
$('#divOne').hide().selectBoxIt();
```

If this still results in a visible delay, you'll need to apply CSS to the select element. This, however, results in the list being unavailable to those without JavaScript.

```
#divOne {display: none;}
```